# Manage multiple forms on one page using renderPartial

Tags: ajax, widget, yii, renderpartial

I want to show multi forms on one page,like first show log in form, after validation/Authentication hide login form and show another form which will take user's billing/shipping info, and if new customer show sign up form on same page and after successful sign up, make it log in and hide sign up form and render billing/shipping form. and same with other forms like credit card information, want to use ajax based validation and rendering.

I am doing this which is not working

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Customers']))
        {
            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
            {
                if(!$model->validate())
                {
                    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                    Yii::app()->end();
                }else{
                    $this->renderBillingShippingForm();
                }

            }

            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='signup-form')
            {
                if(!$model->validate())
                {
                    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                    Yii::app()->end();
                }else{
                    $this->customerSignup($model);
                }


            }


        }
```

Here are functions

```
public function customerSignup($model)
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Customers'];
    if($model->validate())
    {
        $model->password=encrypting($model->password);
        $model->email=$model->email;

        if ($model->save())
        {
            $this->renderBillingShippingForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is another

```
function renderBillingShippingForm()
{
    $billingShippingInfo = new CustomerBillingShippingInfo;
    $this->renderPartial('billing_shipping_form', array("billingShippingInfo"=>$billingShippingInfo));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Any idea

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create two widgets - for login form and for billing. In view file render necessary widget depends from some parameter (like page state). Parameter can by passed by ajax or request.